# In Facebook, is there any way to update an existing photo post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I uploaded a picture and posted it on my wall but I realized that I uploaded the wrong copy of the picture. Is there anyway I can "update" the picture in that post without actually have it show up as a completely new post?

I want to keep all of the comments, etc links to the photo. Is this possible?

Comment: As @dnbrv said, Not possible.

Comment: It's still not possible to do whether or not you offer a bounty. This feature is 100% absent from Facebook.

Comment: It makes no sense for Facebook to even offer this either... you shouldn't be able, as a regular user, to basically move comments over from one picture to another. That could get a lot of people in trouble. :D

Comment: @NathanFrancy - thats a good point . .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. You can't "replace" a picture in Facebook. You'll have to delete the wrong one and upload the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Upload the new photo to the post as an extra photo in the album
2. Delete the old photo in the edit view

(I just had to fix an image post myself, and found this worked :D )

Comment: how did you do it? Do you, by any chance, did it with iOs app?

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the comments and the other answer, it is not possible **BUT** there is a small possibility here:

If you do not directly upload the images to Facebook but instead upload it elsewhere and post a link to the image as a status update, then the photo can be changed by changing the content of the link.

Also, a snapshot of the photo will be shown attached with the status update.

But the minus point here is that the photo will **NOT** be visible from your **Albums**.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've done is to add the updated picture as a comment photo. Then people can clearly see that the comments pertain to the original photo.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the Photo to a different album (create a new one for it).
2. In your photo editor (Photoshop, Preview,..etc. ) "select all" the edited image and "copy"
3. Go to the post on your wall (timeline) and "edit" it
4. Go to the end of your post text and put the cursor there, then click Ctrl+V
5. your new image will be added to the photos of the "new album"
6. delete the old photo and keep the newly added one.
7. save the post.